# Cannot apply an actionBarStyle to my Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I've looked at many posts about styling an ActionBar; specifically, I want to change the background color of the menu overflow. Android seems to ignore my attempts through `actionBarStyle` and `android:actionBarStyle`. Additionally, the auto-complete in Eclipse doesn't show either of these as an option when adding the items. Why can't I access and customize these styles?

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/custom_theme_text_color</item>
    <item name="background">@color/custom_theme_text_color</item>
</style>
```

This does nothing. Any idea why?
(I'm testing on a device above API 14.)

Comment: have you applied your theme in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes I have. I've verified that I can apply changes to things like textColor here, but anything with "actionBarStyle" seems to have no effect.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/. Sometimes style errors are very hard to detect :) I can't see it right now without importing into my IDE.